# FFMPEG force_keyframes multiple / several times

Tags: ffmpeg

I am looking for the correct way to use ffmpeg argument force_key_frames at multiple times in a transcode job. As an example right now I can us force_key_frames 0:00:22 to force a keyframe at 22 seconds, but I need both more granularity forcing at fram level as well as being able to select more time points in the job to have forced key frames.

Maybe one at 3 minutes 32 seconds 15 frames and another at 8 minutes 16 seconds 11 frames and so on.

Comment: Shw the current command you're using.

Comment: I managed to solve part of my own question - it is possible to go force_key_frames 0:00:22,0:00:24 and so on. But being able to be more granular and insert at frame level like 0:00:22:16 is still a problem. Anyone?

Comment: You can't reference frames directly, but you can augment the timestamp with milliseconds, so to force a keyframe at 22:16 in a 30 fps video, use `22.530` `force_keyframes` inserts KF at the frame just after the specified time.

Comment: Aha! Very interesting. Will try this.